# findall() returns a list but it does not add the elements in the list

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
nos="to do with your newfound skills.  338  3803"
for x in nos:
    y=re.findall("[0-9]+",nos)
print("total is :",sum(y))
```

Although the variable y returns a list but still is it mandatory to explicitly mention as y=list() also it gives this error:

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: `y=re.findall("[0-9]+",nos)
print("total is :",sum(map(int, y)))` ?

Comment: Why are you recalculating `y` for every character in `nos`?

Comment: Your first problem is the loop: you repeat the same operation `y=re.findall("[0-9]+",nos)` 43 times , for each character in the string. The loop is not needed. The second problem is that the result is a list of strings, they must be converted to numbers before summation.

Comment: I was actually working with a file but due to error for instance I end up taking line of the file for identifying my error @PatrickHaugh

Comment: Is there an other methodother than map() to convert all the elements of the list to int or float that you would like to suggest @DYZ

Comment: You can use list comprehension, it is usually somewhat faster.

Answer (score 1):

You already have answers that explain why it doesn't work in the comment section, but please consider list comprehension in this case,

```
nos="to do with your newfound skills.  338  3803"
print(sum([int(s) for s in nos.split() if s.isdigit()]))
>>>>4141
```

Or even better as noted by @EdwardMinnix

```
print(sum(int(s) for s in nos.split() if s.isdigit()))
```

Comment: You can also just use `sum(int(s) for ...)` instead by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping, you can try mapping `int` to your string. Here I have used `\d+` to account for the integers. You can very well use `[0-9]+` as you did.

```
import re
nos="to do with your newfound skills.  338  3803"
y = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', nos))
print (sum(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `re.findall("[0-9]+",nos)` returns an `int`, which it doesn't.

Keep in mind that regular expressions works with `str`, so it returns a `str` representation of that integer.

You need to cast it to an `int` to be able to do arithmetic operations on it.

One nice way to achieve this is to make use of the `map` method, which receives a callable and executes it many times as arguments available, returning a `list` of all the outputs.

```
y = map(int, re.findall('[0-9]+', nos))
```

---

## Unrelated notes

Here are a couple of unrelated things i'd like to note:

#### Don't loop over the string

There is no need to loop over the string, as you are not using the iterated characters at all.

```
import re
nos="to do with your newfound skills.  338  3803"
y=map(int, re.findall("[0-9]+",nos))
print("total is :",sum(y))
```

#### You might get away without regular expressions

If you know that the numbers will be separated by spaces, you can change your logic to the following:

```
text = "to do with your newfound skills.  338  3803"
numbers = map(int, filter(str.isdigit, nos.split()))
print (sum(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import re 
def find_sum(str1): 
    # Regular Expression that matches digits in between a string 
    return sum(map(int,re.findall('\d+',str1)))

str1 = input()  
print(find_sum(str1))
```